# Need to install Internet Explorer but getting sha1sum mismatch

Tags: package-management, wine, winetricks, ie

I'm getting this error when we select IE versions:

```
sha1sum mismatch! Rename /home/ascra/.cache/winetricks/ie7/winetest.cat and try again.
```